# How to deal with long invoke chain with micro service

Tags: java, microservices

my project is created with Micro Service architecture, one business may need multiple services call. Currently, most of the services call need serial call, because the request of the next service call is generated from the last service call's response. This makes the invoke chain is very long, the performance is bad, is it any solution to deal with this scenario? Or I need to change my micro service design? Thanks!

Comment: You need to find few more answers before you can get to a solution.
You say performance is bad? quantify it? How much time does it take end to end.
How much time does each of the service takes individually.IF you services are taking majority of time, you need to look into those services. If hops are taking more time then you may have to consider about the partitions of your services and endpoint. What are you doing that is causing these hops.
Isolate the problem, and then you would be able tp solve it.

Comment: @Anunay thanks for your kindly suggestion. Since the call chain is long, every api call is a http requset, too much http requests will degrade the performance.

Comment: Too much , yes. But what is too much. How man hops you have? What is end to end response time. If you have say 20 hops and each hop takes 5 ms on network its 100ms of just hopping, but if you service takes 1000 ms to do actual work, then shaving of these 10ms will not be worth it, rather you need to look into y 1000 ms at servicce layer. If its other way round then you need to look for causes. Is there api gateways, security layer, payload etc. what can you remove. Also consider biz logic. Why such huge calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to solve part of your problem implementing a queue solution like an [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/), the first microservice process the data and post the data in the queue and the second microservice read from this queue.... process and post to another queue.

This approach can improve the performance because you can increase the numbers of partitions into Kafka, but you need to analyze what's you really need to process before sending the task to next service and if this can be paralyzed, if it can be paralyzed you can scale the microservice instances to process more data.

You have many options, but for microservices "talk" I recommend use queues.

Good luck with your project.